# Lunar code magnet,Head first java, pg-314

Tags: java, loops

I am new to java can anyone explain to me how this code works in this example
specially the **LOOP** portion

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
class FullMoons {
    static int DAY_IM = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(2004,0,7,15,40);
        long day1 = c.getTimeInMillis();

        for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++) {
            day1 += (DAY_IM * 29.52);
            c.setTimeInMillis(day1);
            out.println(String.format("full moon on %tc", c));
        }
    }
}
```

output is

```
full moon on Fri Feb 06 04:06:35 MST 2004
full moon on Sat Mar 06 16:38:23 MST 2004
full moon on Mon Apr 05 06:07:11 MDT 2004
```

an answer should be displayed in first three loops why it takes entire 60 runnings

Answer (score 0):

What is the answer and why it should be displayed in first 3 loops?

This code creates Calendar and then added to the first full moon date the duration of lunar month (about 29.52 days).

The cycle body runs 60 times, because condition `x < 60` and `x++` increase x by 1.

```
        //increase number of milliseconds
        day1 += (DAY_IM * 29.52);
        //set increased number to Calendar c
        c.setTimeInMillis(day1);
        //create formatted string
        String s = String.format("full moon on %tc", c);
        //output the string
        out.println(s);
```

read more about how String.format() works in [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: Output is I just written below code....BTW can u please explain in detail that how loop finds when to print the time

Answer (score 0):

This code will run 60 times throughout the Loop..
I realized my mistake which is iam only going by theory rather than doing practical...so guys this is lesson, and iam posting the result so that this question dosent create any unnecessary confusion further.

```
full moon on Fri Feb 06 04:08:48 IST 2004
full moon on Sat Mar 06 16:37:36 IST 2004
full moon on Mon Apr 05 05:06:24 IST 2004
full moon on Tue May 04 17:35:12 IST 2004
full moon on Thu Jun 03 06:04:00 IST 2004
full moon on Fri Jul 02 18:32:48 IST 2004
full moon on Sun Aug 01 07:01:36 IST 2004
full moon on Mon Aug 30 19:30:24 IST 2004
full moon on Wed Sep 29 07:59:12 IST 2004
full moon on Thu Oct 28 20:28:00 IST 2004
full moon on Sat Nov 27 08:56:48 IST 2004
full moon on Sun Dec 26 21:25:36 IST 2004
full moon on Tue Jan 25 09:54:24 IST 2005
full moon on Wed Feb 23 22:23:12 IST 2005
full moon on Fri Mar 25 10:52:00 IST 2005
full moon on Sat Apr 23 23:20:48 IST 2005
full moon on Mon May 23 11:49:36 IST 2005
full moon on Wed Jun 22 00:18:24 IST 2005
full moon on Thu Jul 21 12:47:12 IST 2005
full moon on Sat Aug 20 01:16:00 IST 2005
full moon on Sun Sep 18 13:44:48 IST 2005
full moon on Tue Oct 18 02:13:36 IST 2005
full moon on Wed Nov 16 14:42:24 IST 2005
full moon on Fri Dec 16 03:11:12 IST 2005
full moon on Sat Jan 14 15:40:00 IST 2006
full moon on Mon Feb 13 04:08:48 IST 2006
full moon on Tue Mar 14 16:37:36 IST 2006
full moon on Thu Apr 13 05:06:24 IST 2006
full moon on Fri May 12 17:35:12 IST 2006
full moon on Sun Jun 11 06:04:00 IST 2006
full moon on Mon Jul 10 18:32:48 IST 2006
full moon on Wed Aug 09 07:01:36 IST 2006
full moon on Thu Sep 07 19:30:24 IST 2006
full moon on Sat Oct 07 07:59:12 IST 2006
full moon on Sun Nov 05 20:28:00 IST 2006
full moon on Tue Dec 05 08:56:48 IST 2006
full moon on Wed Jan 03 21:25:36 IST 2007
full moon on Fri Feb 02 09:54:24 IST 2007
full moon on Sat Mar 03 22:23:12 IST 2007
full moon on Mon Apr 02 10:52:00 IST 2007
full moon on Tue May 01 23:20:48 IST 2007
full moon on Thu May 31 11:49:36 IST 2007
full moon on Sat Jun 30 00:18:24 IST 2007
full moon on Sun Jul 29 12:47:12 IST 2007
full moon on Tue Aug 28 01:16:00 IST 2007
full moon on Wed Sep 26 13:44:48 IST 2007
full moon on Fri Oct 26 02:13:36 IST 2007
full moon on Sat Nov 24 14:42:24 IST 2007
full moon on Mon Dec 24 03:11:12 IST 2007
full moon on Tue Jan 22 15:40:00 IST 2008
full moon on Thu Feb 21 04:08:48 IST 2008
full moon on Fri Mar 21 16:37:36 IST 2008
full moon on Sun Apr 20 05:06:24 IST 2008
full moon on Mon May 19 17:35:12 IST 2008
full moon on Wed Jun 18 06:04:00 IST 2008
full moon on Thu Jul 17 18:32:48 IST 2008
full moon on Sat Aug 16 07:01:36 IST 2008
full moon on Sun Sep 14 19:30:24 IST 2008
full moon on Tue Oct 14 07:59:12 IST 2008
full moon on Wed Nov 12 20:28:00 IST 2008
```